# Android log showing 'BLOCKED'

Tags: android, logging, logcat, android-logcat

I'm seeing a new log in the logcat, when I connect my device. After the package name of my App, and a tag, the log message is "BLOCKED".

> `01-19 08:07:40.973 18478-18478/<package_name> I/<tag>: BLOCKED`

Device, app, everything running normally.
Just curious about this log, couldn't find any information.

Configurations...

- Android Studio 2.2.3
- compileSdkVersion 24
- buildToolsVersion 24.0.3
- Gradle 2.14.1

Comment: That seems the part of the logged message.

Comment: @keshav Sorry for the confusion, the reason for asking the question is because it's not part of any Log in the source code. At least not with the specific tag.